# Mapbox studio uploaded tiff displays a blank vertical line at the antimeridian and doesn't extend to the poles

Tags: mapbox, geotiff, mapbox-studio

I have a GeoTIFF file that I'm trying to display in Mapbox Studio, but it displays with a blank vertical line at the antimeridian (the dateline) and the raster doesn't extend to the poles as it should.  The GeoTIFF file was created in Python from RGB numpy array bands that are 1440x721 in dimension ranging from -180 to 180 degrees longitude and 90 to -90 degrees latitude.  The GeoTIFF displays fine in QGIS.

Here is the code snippet that creates the file:

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds_out = driver.Create('gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p25.spd_rgb_10.f012_EPSG_GRIB.tif', 1440, 721, 3, 
gdal.GDT_Byte)
ds_out.SetGeoTransform([-180.125, 0.25, 0, 90.125, 0, -0.25])
ds_out.SetProjection('GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]')
ds_out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(red)
ds_out.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(green)
ds_out.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(blue)
ds_out.FlushCache()
ds_out = None
```

Here is an image of GeoTIFF displayed in Mac OSX Preview:

[screen shot of GeoTIFF displayed in Mac OSX Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpC2g.jpg)

Here are two views of how it displays in Mapbox Studio:

[screen shot of GeoTIFF displayed in Mapbox Studio zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN2ZB.jpg)

[screen shot of GeoTIFF displayed in Mapbox Studio zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKBAO.jpg)

I also tried changing the projection to EPSG:3857 using gdalwarp prior to uploading to Mapbox Studio, but it still displays the same.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  I interpolated my arrays into the EPSG:3857 coordinate system and set the projection of the output file to EPSG:3857:

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds_out = driver.Create('gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p25.spd_rgb_10.f012_EPSG_3857.tif', 
x_size, x_size, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte)
cell_dim = 20037508.34 / 720.0
ds_out.SetGeoTransform([-20037508.34, cell_dim, 0, 20037508.34, 0, -cell_dim])
spatialReference = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
ds_out.SetProjection(spatialReference.ExportToWkt())
ds_out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(red)
ds_out.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(green)
ds_out.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(blue)
ds_out.FlushCache()
ds_out = None
ds_in = None
```